# Adding bootstrap to ember using Bower

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, bower

I am running the following from the root of my project:

```
bower install --save bootstrap
```

it outputs the following:

```
bower bootstrap#*           not-cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower bootstrap#*              resolve git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower bootstrap#*             download https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.2.0.tar.gz
bower bootstrap#*              extract archive.tar.gz
bower bootstrap#*             resolved git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.2.0
bower bootstrap#~3.2.0         install bootstrap#3.2.0
```

But the vendor folder is still empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default bower will install the downloaded components into the *bower_components* directory.
You can override this behavior by declaring an alternative location in the [.bowerrc](http://bower.io/docs/config/) file, for example:

```
{
  "directory": "vendor/assets/components"
}
```

Comment: watching evil trouts demo's it seems like they just go into vendor - is this something he would have had to configure same as this?

Comment: There are many options: configuring bower to use another directory, using grunt to move the component files, using bower-install instead of bower. To which evil trout demo are you referring?

Comment: I've been trying to use it from the bower_components dir too with not much luck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961286/ember-cli-adding-dependencies-with-bower i think the screencast was http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7twifrxOTQY

Comment: Looking at the .bowerrc in the emberreddit github repo it looks like originally he was using "directory": "vendor" and than [switched back](https://github.com/eviltrout/emberreddit/commit/d188eb7985db31681d6dffc35e4e6047c456dbd7) to the default. As far as this question goes this is the reason why the files are not downloaded to the vendor directory.

Comment: cheers - explains that part... still at a loss as to why it won't work when i include it in my brocfile